# PHP PDO how to bind values to varibale contains concatenated string

Tags: php, pdo

How do i bind values to a variable which is partially processed with diffrent statements and then concatenated using php .= method

Please note that I am not using array to bind parameters.
below is piece of code

```
$wher = '';
```

now I have added few varibles to $wher like

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['advs']['title']))
    {
        $wher .= '(';
        if (isset($_SESSION['advs']['desc']))
        {
            $wher .= "(au.description like '%" . $system->cleanvars($_SESSION['advs']['title']) . "%') OR ";
        }
        $wher .= "(au.title like '%" . $system->cleanvars($_SESSION['advs']['title']) . "%' OR au.id = " . intval($_SESSION['advs']['title']) . ")) AND ";
    }
```

more addition to $wher

```
if (isset($_SESSION['advs']['buyitnow']))
    {
        $wher .= "(au.buy_now > 0 AND (au.bn_only = 'y' OR au.bn_only = 'n' && (au.num_bids = 0 OR (au.reserve_price > 0 AND au.current_bid < au.reserve_price)))) AND ";
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['advs']['buyitnowonly']))
    {
        $wher .= "(au.bn_only = 'y') AND ";
    }

    if (!empty($_SESSION['advs']['zipcode']))
    {
        $userjoin = "LEFT JOIN " . $DBPrefix . "users u ON (u.id = au.user)";
        $wher .= "(u.zip LIKE '%" . $system->cleanvars($_SESSION['advs']['zipcode']) . "%') AND ";
    }
```

now I am using $wher in database query like

```
// get total number of records
    $query = "SELECT count(*) AS total FROM " . $DBPrefix . "auctions au
            " . $userjoin . "
            WHERE au.suspended = 0
            AND ".$wher . $ora . "
            au.starts <= " . $NOW . "
            ORDER BY " . $by;
```

$wher is being used in SQL select query.
How do I put placeholders to $wher and bind the values??
my problem is something like [PHP PDO binding variables to a string while concatenating it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16109827/php-pdo-binding-variables-to-a-string-while-concatenating-it)
But slight different way

Comment: What exactly the problem? You can create `field = :value`? Or what?

Comment: No one will read this piece of code. Where's the problem exactly?

Comment: Your question is of a low value, please be polite against @u_mulder he is asking deliberate questions to try to help you. What you are posting in the comments is unreadable. While your question is very hard to understand, smaller snippets and error explanations would improve this question a lot.

Comment: I have edited my question. Hope someone understands it